# 'Array<(Object)>' is not convertible to 'Bool'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, filter

Say there's a class called `Post` (as in a forum post).

```
class Post: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var title: String?
    @NSManaged var body: String?
    @NSManaged var voteCount: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var thread: Thread?
}
```

And a `Thread` class.

```
class Thread: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var topic: String
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var posts: NSSet
}
```

A thread contains a set of `Post` objects.

From the local core data database I retrieve an array of `Thread` objects to `var threads = [Thread]()`.

[image]

Now I need to filter out posts in threads that have a vote count of more than 0. In other words I need an array of `Thread` objects excluding the `Post`s with 0 votes.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
var filteredThreads = threads.filter() { $0.posts.filter() { $0.voteCount > 0 } }
```

But I get the error **'Array<(Post)>' is not convertible to 'Bool'**.

It seems I cannot use nested filters like this. Or am I doing it wrong?

---

**Edit:** I also tried the below code. No compile time errors but it doesn't filter the returned results array as expected.

```
threads = items.filter() {
    for post in $0.posts.allObjects as [Post] {
        if post.voteCount!.integerValue > 0 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I uploaded a Xcode project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8pn6qae15dq03ap/Forum.zip?dl=0) demonstrating the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

---

**Attempt 2:** I tried iterating through the `Thread` objects I receive and filter out the `Post`s inside it. But I don't know how to add the filtered array back to the `Thread` object.

```
if let items = viewModel.getThreads() {
    for thread in items {
        let posts = thread.posts.allObjects as [Post]
        var s = posts.filter() {
            if $0.voteCount!.integerValue > 0 {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method cannot work. You cannot filter the Thread objects in such a
way that you get an array of "modified" Thread objects which are only
related to the Posts with positive vote count. Filtering gives always a
subset of the original objects, but those objects are not modified.

The proper way to achieve what you want is to fetch all Post objects
with positive vote count, and group them into sections according to
their Thread.

The easiest way to do so is a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Here is a quick-and-dirty version of your ForumViewController that
uses a fetched results controller. Most of it is the boilerplate code
that you get with a standard "Master-Detail Application + Core Data"
in Xcode. It certainly can be improved but hopefully should get you
on the right track.

To make this compile in your sample project, `managedObjectContext`
in the `ForumViewModel` needs to be a public property.
Alternatively, you can move the fetched results controller creation
into the `ForumViewModel` class.

```
// ForumViewController.swift:
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ForumViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    private let viewModel = ForumViewModel()

    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }

        // Fetch "Post" objects:
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Post")

        // But only those with positive voteCount:
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "voteCount > 0")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        // First sort descriptor must be the section key:
        let topicSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "thread.topic", ascending: true)
        // Second sort descriptor to sort the posts in each section:
        let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [topicSort, titleSort]

        // Fetched results controller with sectioning according the thread.topic:
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                managedObjectContext: viewModel.managedObjectContext,
                sectionNameKeyPath: "thread.topic", cacheName: nil)
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
            abort()
        }
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }
    var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let post = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Post
        cell.textLabel!.text = post.title
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(post.voteCount!)"
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
        return sectionInfo.name
    }

    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
        case .Insert:
            self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
        }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Update:
            self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
        case .Move:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`$0.posts.filter() { $0.voteCount > 0 }` returns an array of `Post` that `voteCount` is positive. You have to check the `count` of it:

```
var filteredThreads = threads.filter() {
    $0.posts.filter({ $0.voteCount > 0 }).count > 0
    //                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

But, this unconditionally iterates all `posts`. Instead, you should `return true` as soon as possible:

```
var filteredThreads = threads.filter() {
    for p in $0.posts {
        if p.voteCount > 0 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But I can't seem to get this to work. Although the code compiles without and error, the same old set of results are displayed. I updated my original question with more clarification and info. Can you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

That function inside filter must return something with type 'Bool'

I think this following code might come handy for you

```
var filteredThreads = threads.filter({
   var result = false;
   for (var i = 0; i<$0.posts.count;i++) {
      if ($0.posts[i].voteCount > 0){
           result = true;
      }
   }
   return result
})
```

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82599/swift-functional-programming-tutorial) blog post might become usefull

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried a similar solution as posted by @rintaro with a for in loop but unfortunately it didn't filter out the array properly. I thought I was too vague before so I updated my original question above with more info. If you can please take another look.